# How to create a client for a spring boot service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, crud

I have a simple CRUD API for a Spring Boot service based on [this example](https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-crud-spring-boot-20-minutes).

The API is provided with the following definition:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

From a curl client, I can get the list of users using the following implicit `GET` command: `curl localhost:8080/persons`.

From Java's perspective we just called the remote equivalent of `Iterable<Person> persons = personRepository.findAll()`.

**The question** is whether spring can auto-create a remote implementation (client) of the same API **without** the need to manually type paths or know the method type (like needed when using `RestTemplate`)?

Example of an such a client usage:

```
PersonRepository personRepository = new PersonRepositoryClient(http://localhost:8080");
Iterable<Person> persons = personRepository.findAll(); // findAll does a remote call as if it was local.
```

How can I get to such a client "generated" implementation"?

* I know that passing the URL directly contradicts the service discovery architecture, but it's just for the sake of understanding how to get to a well defined client. The same client can be used within a service discovery architecture, by discovering the URL instead of manually setting it.

Comment: I guess the starting point will be to enable Spring HATEOAS ( http://projects.spring.io/spring-hateoas/ ) on your rest service.

Comment: I take it back the `@RepositoryRestResource` already enables HATEOAS

Answer (score 0):

Try [Feign Client](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html). It provides autogeneration of HTTP request handlers for your Java interfaces. To make it work, you need to include Spring Cloud, standard Spring framework doesn't have this feature.

Comment: I see that Feign uses different annotations than Spring (and different from JAX-RS), like `@RequestLine`. I'm looking for a mechanism to read `@RequestMapping` and other Spring annotations.