# How to create a java client for a Spring service?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jax-rs

I have a service definition using Spring annotations. Example ([source](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping)):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ex/foos/{id}", method = GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getFoosBySimplePathWithPathVariable(
  @PathVariable("id") long id) {
    return "Get a specific Foo with id=" + id;
}
```

The question is whether spring (or another library) can auto-create a remote implementation (client) of the same API without the need to manually type paths, method type, param names, etc. (like needed when using RestTemplate)?

Example of an such a client usage:

```
FooClient fooClient = new FooClient("http://localhost:8080");
String foo = fooClient.getFoosBySimplePathWithPathVariable(3l);
```

How can I get to such a client "generated" implementation"?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682312/how-to-create-a-client-for-a-spring-boot-service

Comment: What about Swagger? Reading about Swagger, I couldn't find a direct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [Feign Client](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html). It does everything you need: calling one service via HTTP is similar to calling method of Java interface. But to make it work you need Spring Cloud, standard Spring framework doesn't have this feature yet.

Comment: I see that Feign uses different annotation than Spring (and JAS-RS) : `@RequestLine`. I'm looking for a mechanism to read `@RequestMapping` and other Spring annotations.

Comment: Feign Client is a part of Spring Cloud ecosystem (which may be considered as 'a part of Spring') and is the most default way to generate http-client wrappers for your code. See [7.1 of official Spring Cloud documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#netflix-feign-starter): Feign can be used with existing `@RequestMapping` controllers.

Comment: Tried using feign (`Api api = Feign.builder().target(Api.class, "http://localhost:8080"); api.getFoosBySimplePathWithPathVariable();`) with the following definition: `@RequestMapping(value="/whtever", method=RequestMethod.GET)`. Got `Method ... not annotated with HTTP method type` :( It seems that feign isn't that comfortable with `@RequestMapping` :(

Comment: You can see [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#netflix-feign-starter) (see StoreClient.java section) that classical approach of using Feign is interface-based. Instead of annotating with `@RequestMapping` your class methods, you should annotate interface methods, and then to build http implementation you can just annotate the whole interface as `@FeignClient`.

Comment: i see our brains are still thinking in the old way of doing things. feign is awesome

Answer (score 0):

You can generate it using [Swagger Editor](https://swagger.io/swagger-editor/). You shoud just define the path of the resources and then it'll generate for you the client for almost any language of your choice

Comment: How would I use Swagger to create the client side code?

Comment: Once you have defined your endpoints structure in Swagger Editor into the toolbar you have a menu called "Generate Client", you choose the language you need and it's done

Comment: I don't have the online editor. I just have the server side annotation, e.g. `@RequestMapping(value = "/ex/foos/{id}", method = GET)...`.